# How can I check if a field exists for a specific _id in mongodb collections?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-administration

I want to check if a specific _id in a collection has a field named 'report'. How do I do this in MongoDB?

Suppose my _Id is Je4F8X. All I want to do is to know if my asynchronous task has updated the DB with the output in the field 'report'.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can fetch particular document with given _id and then check if doc.report == 'yourvalue'.

Comment: "yourvalue" is a varying value. It is an output from a tool. Not constant. Suppose in 
 a scenario the tool didn't run properly, the report field may not get updated. So if doc['report'] doesn't exist, the app would end up in a Key Error Exception.

Comment: If you just want to check if the field report is added to the document by the 'tool' then you can simply use mongodb `exists` query

Answer (score 0):

To check if the field `report` is added to the document(earlier it was not present) by the 'tool' then you can simply use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query,

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({_id:yourId, report:{$exists:true}})
```

If field was already present and want to check if it is updated with latest value use [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/).
This can work if storing output from tool in `updatedValue` is possible.

```
 db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({_id:yourId, report:{$eq:updatedValue}})
```